# SQLite, MySQLdb to open .db file conceptual Python process

Tags: python, sqlite, ubuntu-11.04, mysql-python

I have a db file that I would like to open, process the data within and re-save as another db file to be inserted into a MySQLdb database.
I have read that the only way to open a db file is with SQLlite. I'm working in Ubuntu 11.04.
I need to write the process code in Python.
What is the correct conceptual procedure to do this?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the .db file using sqlite3 (http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html)? If you can't get the data processing you need by executing SQL statements you can always pull out the data and perform the necessary processing steps with Python.

Comment: Run `file /path/to/your.db` from your terminal.  if it's output is not something like `SQLite 3.x database` then you don't have a sqlite database at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) for this type of problem. You can use it to

1. Open your SQLite3 DB and figure out the schema
2. Save that schema as a sqlalchemy model
3. < OPTIONAL do any processing you like >
4. Using the same sqlalchemy model from 1, open a MySQL connection, create the tables and load the data

Note I - you can do all this with the django ORM too - but the SQLAlchemy route will allow you to have less redundant code and more future flexibility.

Note II - [sqlautocode](http://code.google.com/p/sqlautocode/) can help you with 1.